# No attention or any comment on this question yet. Should it be migrated to math.SE?

Tags: discussion

I have not got any attention/comment on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/266958/14414) yet, even after being in bounty for 4 days. Meanwhile I learned that the problem has trivial solution in higher dimensions (minimum value = 0), but that not seem to be the case in single
($d = 1$) dimension. If this is a myth, I'd like someone to bust it with a counter example or a hint. But I am not getting any attention on that as well. So I wonder if I should consider migrating it to math.SE, if its absolutely sure that it is not suitable here. It is still under bounty.

I am interested in the single dimension case, to obtain a solution if its not trivial.

**EDIT : Update**

This question was migrated upon my request, and just got an [amazing answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2260325/2987) over there.

Comment: Your question has 4 upvotes, the bounty is still active, and nobody suggested that your question should better be migrated to math.SE or would otherwise be off-topic. -- So why not just wait?

Comment: Question with an active bounty cannot be migrate - you have to wait until the bounty ends. An alternative would be to ask moderators to cancel the bounty. See [Can a question with an open bounty on it be migrated from M.SE to MO?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11807) and [What happens to a bounty question if it gets migrated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38819).

Comment: I think I will to wait till someone suggests to migrate.

Comment: Migrated to math.SE : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2249528/2987